# Altium Designer: How to select different subcircuits in Schematic and on PCB?

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I've created three sheet symbol from the same sheet, and gave different designators to each of them. Update the PCB, and now I want to place components. But I can not select the components of each subcircuit separately. I don't know how?!

[image: Subcircuits]

If I select any component from the sheet (That I've derived ARC1, ARC2 and ARC3 from) it selects the components of all three ARC's. How can I select the component of only ARC1?

Comment: You need treat this design as a Multi-Channel design. See [Altium support](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Creating+a+Multi-channel+Design) which describes how to set up a sheet symbol for Multi-Channel.

Comment: What do you mean by (How can I select the component) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the steps:

1. Go to View > Workspace Panels > PCB > PCB
2. Go to PCB Tab.
3. Here you will see component classes. Here you have the option of selecting components present on the top layer, bottom later etc. You can also choose components from different schematic docs.
4. Select your sheet (for ex ARC1) and you shall be able to see the number of components on that sheet right below the component classes.
5. Select the component from this list and the same shall be highlighted in your PCB.